# Spring boot thymeleaf display of productName

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to display of my productName, but there is Error as:

```
ERROR 10464 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             
: [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-6] Exception processing template 
"/productView/productPage": An error happened during template parsing 
(template: "class path resource 
[templates//productView/productPage.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened 
during template parsing (template: "class path resource 
[templates//productView/productPage.html]")



@Controller
public class ProductController {

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@GetMapping("productAdmin")
public String next(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("eProduct",new Product());
    return "/adminView/productAdmin";
}

@GetMapping("/productPage")
public String productPage(){
    return "/productView/productPage";
}


@PostMapping("/saveProduct")
public String save(@ModelAttribute("eProduct")  Product product, BindingResult result,
                   @RequestParam("pathImage") MultipartFile multipartFile ){
    String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "projectImages\\";

    try {
        multipartFile.transferTo(new File(path + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    product.setPathImage("\\images\\" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    productService.save(product);
    return "/mainView/index";
}

@GetMapping("/products")
public String products(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("products",productService.findAll());
    return "/productView/products";
}

@GetMapping("/product-{id}")
public String productPage(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
    Product product = productService.findOne(id);
    model.addAttribute("product",product);
    return "/productView/productPage";
}

}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 Product Page
<p><span th:text="${product.productName}"/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But I don't reason of this issue.
In spring I write

${product.productName}

and my code was working good.But in this situation I don't understand what I do wrong. 
Could you please help me with this problem. Because I don't know what to do next, I tried to do myself but it did not work out.

Thank you.

Comment: From the full stacktrace you added on a comment to an answer below, the error comes from using "${product.id}", but your question code is missing this html fragment: "Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "product.id" (template: "productView/productPage""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your error, in the log that you uploaded in a comment, I saw that the error's cause was the following:

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "product.id" (template: "productView/productPage" - line 10, col 4)
```

So that menas that either your product's model doesn't have getters for that field, you are not using the correct name for that field or you are sending a null value. So investigating further, I found this other message.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null
```

So it means that your product's id is null. In oder to fix this, you need to change your code for one of the following options.

```
<span th:text="${product.id != null} ? ${product.id} : 'null'></span>
<span th:text="${product?.id}"></span>
```

The last option is call "safe navigation". I haven't use it. I have only used the first one, but it should work too. More information on safe navigation can be found here. [[safe navigation]](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation)

One more thing, I can't see the fragment where `${product.id}` is being called, but doing what I just sent you should work.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Check the syntax of your template maybe you are missing a closing tag

Comment: As you can see tag <meta charset="UTF-8"/> is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I see double slashes (//) in the error log:
templates//productView/productPage.html

Try changing your code to this:

```
@GetMapping("/productPage")
public String productPage(){
return "productView/productPage";
}
```

Comment: Still the same error? Is the path updated in the error log?